# CSS image zoom and center on hover

Tags: html, css, image, hover, zooming

Possible to zoom and center an image on hover with only CSS?

For instance:

[image]

Code below will only zoom:

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/6r0bx6ba/1/

```css
.floatl {
  float: left;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.submain {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.zoomin img {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}

.zoomin img:hover {
  width: 300px;
}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="zoomin submain">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
  <div class="zoomin submain">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
  <div class="zoomin submain">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you do a `translate` as well, then the problem is that the image will move out from under the cursor and will no longer be hovered.

Comment: correct! i don't recommend hover to zoom, how about doing click then do the animation you want?

Comment: I'd rather avoid this using Javascript. So there's no way to achieve this with pure CSS, translate or not?

Answer (score 1):

What about to add when hover on image:
for example to the first one (I add class to cout the img)

```
margin-left:70px;
margin-top:70px;
```

```css
.floatl {
  float: left;
}

.main {
  width: 100%;
}

.submain {
  width: 30%;
  float: left;
}

.zoomin img {
  width: 200px;
  -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
  -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
  -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
  transition: all 1s ease;
}


.a  img:hover{
   margin-left:100px;
    margin-top:70px;}
.b  img:hover{
  
    margin-top:70px;}

.c  img:hover{
   margin-left:-70px;
    margin-top:70px;}
```

```html
<div class="main">
  <div class="zoomin submain a">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
  <div class="zoomin submain b">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
  <div class="zoomin submain c">
    <img src="https://www.google.it/images/branding/googlelogo/2x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png" title="All you need to know about CSS Transitions " />
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nice! I appreciate the effort! Any solution to make this position-independent, so that the image will be centred beyond the original position?